# Can port be changed for HTMLAnchorElement?

Tags: javascript

```
a=document.createElement('a')
<a>​</a>​
a.port="123"
"123"
a.port
""
```

Any ways to change the port? I found that the HTMLAnchorElement is using URLUtils interface. But I dont know how to figure out whether the port can be changed or not.

Comment: do you mean the port number of the url?

Answer (score 2):

It first needs to have an `href` to work with:

```
a=document.createElement('a')
a.setAttribute('href', 'http://example.com');
```

Then, you should be able to use the `port` property to modify it:

```
a.port = "123";

a.port;
// "123"

a.href;
// "http://example.com:123/"
```

[Example](http://jsconsole.com/?var%20a%20%3D%20document.createElement%28%27a%27%29%3B%0Aa.setAttribute%28%27href%27%2C%20%27http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%27%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28a.href%29%3B%0A%0Aa.port%20%3D%20%22123%22%3B%0Aconsole.log%28a.port%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28a.href%29%3B)

Answer (score 1):

The port is not part of the anchor tag directly. It's part of the href attribute

```
<a href="http://www.someUrl.com:80">LinkText</a>
```

The port number goes after the `:`